# SQL IN clause bloat vs INNER JOIN performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Consider a large query with a lot of joins, only to select out IDs from the result. This list of IDs is fed into another query using a IN clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
WHERE col_1 IN (SELECT col 
                FROM table_b 
                INNER JOIN table_c ... 
                INNER JOIN table_d ... )
```

I believe there is a limit to how many values you can pass to an IN clause, hence I'm considering a JOIN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT col 
     FROM table_b 
     INNER table_c...
     INNER JOIN table_d ... )
```

But the latter  is worse in terms of performance since the subquery would be run for every row.

Is this understanding correct? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Instead of joining to the subquery, join to table_b and keep the rest of the join chain. Why do you think joining to the subquery will cause the subquery to execute for every row? It is not a `LATERAL` join. Instead of trying to guess at the execution behavior, run each query with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` to see how each behaves. This approach would be much better than asking the SO community since we don't have sufficient details (PostgreSQL version, table DDL with indexes, full queries, explain plans, table sizes, etc.) to make an informed assessment.

Comment: If the subquery returns duplicates, the two queries aren't exchangeable. Anyway, I say trust the optimizer. But compare the explain outputs to be sure.

Comment: @Martin Version 8.0 is EOL since October 2010, almost 13 years ago. Not to mention the 17 major releases that came after 8.0 Outdated versions like this are completely useless